How can I confirm that a contractor found online is legitimate?
I'm a first time home owner. My fascia is a mess so I'm getting aluminum fascia and soffit install. Thing is it's gonna cost about 5k and they are asking for 50% deposit (which makes sense for materials and such). I was sent a estimate and everything but I'm still scared I could be getting scammed. I have google them and they have websites and everything but like, how do I know for sure it's all legit? It's just a big chunk of money. Someone help me.

Should have more than one quote for that amount of money.  Asking your neighbours/friends about contractors is good.  Checking the local BBB also does not hurt.  Do a search online for reviews for the business.  Make sure the reviews are from third party sites, not from the business site.

Don’t pay cash, have a written contract that specifies all they plan to do, check that their license is valid (if applicable), check that their insurance and workers comp exists and is up to date (this means getting the name of the carrier and the policy number and actually calling the insurance company to verify).

And get scheduling in writing too—start and completion dates.

Does this answer your question? What do you do/ask when hiring a contractor?

Btw, in some states (eg California), deposits are capped by law; $2.5 grand for this job would be illegal.

Ask the contractor for multiple references from past clients. Reach out to said clients and ask about their experience. If they have no references, I'd look elsewhere. If they have references and they report good interaction, this should appease your anxiety and fear.

I think this is a good idea because their response will tell you a lot. A good contractor should have no issues supplying references, and if they hesitate or make excuses that's a bad sign.  But I don't think this alone is enough for a major expenditure - secondary quotes in addition would be helpful too.

I got other quotes and this was the lower one. I found them in google but the name was given by a friend, they do not remember if the number was the same or not. I asked to pay by credit card and they are saying their system is down.

I have been in this industry for 25 years this already sounds suspicious. Cheaper in the Construction industry does not mean better. I would take a look at all the suggestions above and apply them. You will almost always get your moneys worth paying a little more regarding construction. Even if you choose the next higher quote, due diligence and vetting as mentioned above is still in order.
